# if else condition inside function in controller - angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Still new to angular

How to do a if else condition inside the function $scope.change in the controller

I want to do it like this of $scope.SomeValue == 1 then  $scope.fn1() should get execute, if $scope.SomeValue == 2 then $scope.fn2 else $scope.fn3.

I have tried traditional if else, app still works but takes default values defined in the last function as soon as i change an dynamic value through slider or input box

HTML

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="SomveValue.value" name="a" value="1" ng-click="fn1()">
<input type="radio" ng-model="SomveValue.value" name="a" value="2" ng-click="fn2()">
<input type="radio" ng-model="SomveValue.value" name="a" value="3">
```

Controller

```
$scope.Somevalue = {
 value: 1
}
$scope.fn1 = {
  // Some Code
}
$scope.fn2 = {
  // Some Code
}
$scope.fn3 = {
  // Some Code
}
$scope.change = {
  $scope.fn1();
  $scope.fn2();
  $scope.fn3();
}
```

Comment: `ng-modal` ? - don't you mean `ng-model`?

Comment: thanks for the correction

Comment: @akash where did u use this `$scope.change` method in your app?

Comment: Did my answer help you, or is it still not clear?

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for help that was the mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) for this use case. You can specify a expression and define, whap happens with which value.

```
<ANY ng-switch="Somevalue.value">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="1"><a ng-click="fn1()"></a></ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="2"><a ng-click="fn2()"></a></ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply brother but its seems that the main problem is writing ng-modal is place of ng-model.
And thanks you taught me something new